# Removal of table primary key in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, primary-key

I've removed the primary key of one table of my MySQL database, but now, when I use the MySQL Administrator and try to edit some data of this table, it doesn't allow me to do this.

The button **edit** that appears in the bottom of the table keeps visible, but disabled to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "edit" button in MySQL Administrator will use the primary key to determine the query to run.  For example - `UPDATE some_field FROM some_table WHERE id = uid;`  If you'd like to continue using the "edit" button, you'll have to add back a primary key.  If a primary key is not appropriate you can also update your rows using the `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 1):

That's likely because it doesn't know which row you want to have the update applied to, since without a primary key identifier it could match multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alter table tableX add primary key(id);
```

Replace id with your primary key column(s).